# kubernetes/ingress-nginx creates huge number of sync events

Tags: kubernetes, events, ingress-nginx

I noticed that during the [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) pod creation/termination, there is a huge number of events created. Further "investigation" showed that each nginx pod creates

```
42s         Normal    Sync     ingress/name    Scheduled for sync
```

event for each ingress objects.

For perspective, with some approximate imaginary numbers:

- The moment you `kubectl rollout restart ingress-nginx` all ingress-nginx pods will terminate (not simultaneously as there is a proper PDB setup).
- During restart, each pod will create `sync` event object for each ingress object in the cluster.
- So if there are 100 ingress-nginx pods with 500 ingress objects, that will span 50k sync events.

> I could not find any mentions about it in the docs/ingress-nginx issues

**The question**: is it expected behavior?

Comment: Could you please provide with more details: what's done; logs; yaml file; nginx config file? There might be a misconfiguration, therefore your details will help to resolve your issue. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint @Bazhikov. I was particularly hesitant to give the exact configuration of the ingress-nginx. As my main question here was not really about "how to fix it" but more "do people noticed the same `m*n` number of k8s sync events created" and if so "do you consider it a problem at all"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

As we can see [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/6499393772ee786179b006b423e11950912e8295/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go#L378), this is an informer, which creates the sync event for each valid ingress. In turn, this informer is added to the store on each ingress-controller pod, see more [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/intro/how-nginx-ingress-controller-works/).